# PHP blueprinting\analyst

Tags: php, analysis, system, blueprint

Im new to PHP, and was wondering the best way to 'blueprint' a PHP application. I cant find any solid fundamental way to do this. Any suggestions\resources would be helpful. Right now we are taking a site thats procedural based, but want to take it to OO based for the new version.

Comment: Can you specify what kind of "blueprint" you want to end up with?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link discussing site blueprints:

http://www.cyber-sierra.com/workshops/web101/prepare.htm

However for coding the actual PHP I recommend:

1. List all of the features of the site.
2. Describe each feature in detail.
3. List the classes that you are going to write.
4. Describe the variables and methods for each class.
5. Create all of the skeleton code for the classes.
6. Write the actual code for the classes.

If you are new to PHP...make sure that you know the language well before trying to delve into a big project like what it seems that you may be doing.

Either way:  good luck!  Proper planning is the key to successful PHP programming and also helps you avoid any big problems in the middle of the project.